# STL name for the "map" functional programming function

Tags: c++, map-function

I would like to be able to write something like

```
char f(char);
vector<char> bar;
vector<char> foo = map(f, bar);
```

The `transform` function appears to be similar, but it will not autogenerate the size of the resultant collection.

Comment: I think somebody had too much Perl. I have tried to implement something like that in C++ once, but very soon it became highly inefficient: unlike C++, Perl has high-level optimizer which knows what array or hash or string are and optimizes operations on them correspondently.

Comment: The STL has `std::map` as a collection. You can have your own `map` in any other namespace.

Comment: @Dummy: `map` is present in Perl, Python, and Lisps; it's a convenient high-level construct to simply describe a common operation.

Comment: @MSalters: It's more a question of *searching* for the map operation in the STL than the actual name. :-)

Comment: What you’re looking for nowadays is called “ranges”, and exists as external libraries, and will end up in the language standard itself at some point.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `std::back_inserter` in `<iterator>`, although providing the size in front is more efficient. For example:

```
string str = "hello world!", result;
transform(str.begin(), str.end(), back_inserter(result), ::toupper);
// result == "HELLO WORLD!"
```

Comment: +1 -- You can use `std::vector<t>::reserve` in order to remove the efficiency penalty as well.

Answer (score 29):

This question was asked before the C++11 standard went into effect... nowadays we have `std::transform()` as the (ugly) equivalent of a functional programming 'map'. Here's how to use it:

```
auto f(char) -> char; // or if you like: char f(char)
vector<char> bar;
vector<char> foo;
// ... initialize bar somehow ...
std::transform(bar.begin(), bar.end(), std::back_inserter(foo), f);
```

Answer (score 4):

To make this work, you'll need the following observations:

1. To make the assignment efficient, the `map` function should *not* do the work. Instead, it should save its arguments in a temporary object (in your case, that would be an instance of `class map::result<char(*)(char), vector<char> >`)
2. This `map::result` temporary should have an `template <typename T> operator T` conversion.
3. When the `map::result` is assigned to a `std::vector<char>`, this conversion is the only viable.
4. In the conversion operator `class map::result<char(*)(char), vector<char> >::operator vector<char>` you have the input and return type, and the mapping function. At this point you can effectively transform the inputs.

`<edit>`

## Code

```
template<typename CONT, typename FUNC>
class mapresult {
    CONT const& in;
    FUNC f;
public:
    template<typename RESULT> RESULT to() const
    {
        RESULT out;
        for (auto const& e : in) { out.push_back(f(e)); }
        return out;
    }
    template<typename RESULT> operator RESULT() const
    {
        return this->to<RESULT>();
    }
    mapresult(CONT const& in, FUNC f) : in(in), f(std::move(f)) { }
};

template<typename CONT, typename FUNC>
auto map(CONT const& in, FUNC f) -> mapresult<CONT, FUNC>
{
    return mapresult<CONT, FUNC>(in, f);
}
```

## Use like this:

```
using namespace std;
char foo(char c) { return c | ('A' ^ 'a'); }
std::string in = "Test";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string out = map(in, &foo);
    cout << out << endl;

    char replace = 'e';
    cout << map(in, [replace](char c){return c == replace ? '?' : c; }).to<string>();
}
```

Comment: @JohannesGerer: The `map` function doesn't know the target container. it would be inefficient to store the mapped output to a `std::deque<char>` only to discover that it was really needed in a `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: An obvious improvement would be to SFINAE in a call to `.reserve(in.size()`. The main problem is assigning the result to a class with an overloaded assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You can mimic the map syntax above with something like

```
template<typename T, typename A>
T map(A(*f)(A), T & container) {
    T output;
    std::transform(container.begin(), container.end(), std::back_inserter(output), f);
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `std::transform` function does the job, but isn't performant in some cases. I would suggest using a `while` loop and reserving the size before hand. This function can easily be changed to be used with strings or any thing mappable for that matter.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename C>
std::vector<T> map(const std::vector<C> &array, auto iteratee) {
  int index = -1;
  int length = array.size();
  std::vector<T> v(length);
  while(++index < length) {
    v[index] = iteratee(array[index], index);
  }
  return v;
}
```

Calling the function where `array` is the std::vector you want to
map.

```cpp
auto result = map<int, int>(array, [](int elem, int index) {
  return elem + 10;
});
```

Running map on 100 000 000
with `std::transform` took ~6.15s

the while loop version took ~3.90s